# Build failed for IOS when rebuilding React Native project

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am rebuilding my React Native 0.67.4 project by `yarn add` module one by one with Xcode 13/cocoapods 1.15. After a few modules added, run `pod install` and `npx react-native run-ins` to test with IOS 15 emulator. The following error occurs after a few module added and `pod install` successfully. I sense that the error is pod related but don't know how to fix it. Here is the error

```
/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTActionSheetManager.mm:98:35: error: no member named 'cancelButtonTintColor' in 'JS::NativeActionSheetManager::SpecShowActionSheetWithOptionsOptions'
      [RCTConvert UIColor:options.cancelButtonTintColor() ? @(*options.cancelButtonTintColor()) : nil];
                          ~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTActionSheetManager.mm:98:72: error: no member named 'cancelButtonTintColor' in 'JS::NativeActionSheetManager::SpecShowActionSheetWithOptionsOptions'
      [RCTConvert UIColor:options.cancelButtonTintColor() ? @(*options.cancelButtonTintColor()) : nil];
                                                               ~~~~~~~ ^
2 errors generated.

......

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/macair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xyz_app6-drkombcrczieyyfirepznaljzqwr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-CoreModules.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTActionSheetManager.o /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTActionSheetManager.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-CoreModules' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the below steps:

1. delete `node_modules` folder
2. `npm install` or `yarn install`
3. delete `pods` folder and `Podfile.lock` file
4. `cd ios && pod install`
5. Run the project `npx react-native run-ios`

Hope it works!

Comment: Is there an actual fix for this? Wiping out state like this is almost the equivalent of saying "just reboot your system and try again." Heh.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried cleaning everything but it didn't work for me. In the end the issue was related to the iOS deployment target of the React-Codegen pod. Changing it to my project's minimum iOS version worked for me. See this comment; https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34126#issuecomment-1492157907